# Placeholders doesn't work in ValidationFailure message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to make [placeholders](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/e.-Custom-Validators#using-a-custom-message-placeholder) work with my `ValidationFailure`. The below example is a simplified version of what's going on.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var errors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
    errors.Add(new ValidationFailure("PropertyName", "{PropertyValue} is not a valid value.", 42));

    var result = new ValidationResult(errors);
    result.AddToModelState(ModelState, null);

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
    "PropertyName": [
        "{PropertyValue} is not a valid value."
    ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "PropertyName": [
        "42 is not a valid value."
    ]
}
```

I can see these methods on the `ValidationFailure` object. So I'm thinking I just need to send it to the right service to make the magic happen :)

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the formatted message arguments.
/// These are values for custom formatted message in validator resource files
/// Same formatted message can be reused in UI and with same number of format placeholders
/// Like "Value {0} that you entered should be {1}"
/// </summary>
public object[] FormattedMessageArguments { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the formatted message placeholder values.
/// </summary>
public Dictionary<string, object> FormattedMessagePlaceholderValues { get; set; }
```

[source](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/de244de630376a92b4e0a6fc0ad3c4e1f45f1182/src/FluentValidation/Results/ValidationFailure.cs#L79-L90)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know you've simplified the example a lot here, but given that you are *explicitly* creating an instance of `ValidationFailure` in your example, why do you need a placeholder at all?

Comment: I need to do it because I need to change the PropertyName when the ValidationFailure bubbles up the stack. If that makes sense. For example a service/command deep in my core throws an ValidationException (it has ValidationFailures inside) I need to inspect the failures and change the PropertyName where appropriate so the API consumer get a relateable propertyname

Comment: I also made a GitHub issue where the owner of FluentValidation replied https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/616